# How can I change my algorithm to get the farthest node for each iteration?

Tags: java, algorithm, distance, euclidean-distance

So I am trying to pick out the farthest node for each iteration. I start by randomly picking the first node, then continueing by picking the farthest node from the first one.

From there I have two nodes which I want to compare in distance (I am using the euclidean metric) with the rest of the nodes. Then I add the one that is farthest away over both already picked nodes and continue this process, until I have chosen k nodes.

```
Node maxDistNode = null;
        k = k - pickedNodes.size(); //in this case pickedNodes has 2 entries already
        while(k > 0) {
            for(Node pickedN: pickedNodes) {
                for(Node notpickedN: allNodes) { 
                    if(notpickedN.distance < distanceBetween(notpickedN, pickedN)) { //distanceBetween(Node a, Node b) is method that returns Math.hypot(a.x - b.x, a.x - b.x)
                        notpickedN.distance = distanceBetween(notpickedN, pickedN);
                    }
                }
                maxDistNode = Collections.max(allNodes, new Comparator<Node>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Node o1, Node o2) {
                        if(o1.distance > o2.distance) {
                            return 1; 
                        }
                        if(o1.distance == o2.distance) {
                            return 0;
                        }
                        return -1;
                    }
                });
            }
            if(maxDistNode != null) {
                maxDistNode.setPicked(true);
                pickedNodes.add(maxDistNode);
                allNodes.remove(maxDistNode);
                --k;
            }
            
        }
```

Nodes have initially a distance of Integer.MIN_VALUE given. Now the problem is, that this works fine for when k is very small, though when ever I want to search for more nodes this will give me the same one for k-times. Therefore I am left with many duplicate nodes.
How can I change this so I can get the farthest node over all newly added and old pickNodes?

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, I think you want to know the longest distance between two nodes dynamically. You can think of a sorted tree and you put each node based on a distance from a certain coordinate point. So, the leftmost and rightmost nodes are the farthest nodes.

Comment: Do you mean `\sum_i (x_i - p)^2`?